# How to iterate through array of objects in template literals and use function for each of those objects?

Tags: javascript

please advise how to do it right. I have:

1. Array of Objects
2. Class method:

   ```
   buildItem(obj){
      let item = `<div class="${obj.name}">
                    <h1 class="main-title">${obj.title}<h1>
                    <img src="${obj.img}" alt="${obj.alt}">
                  </div>`
      return item;
   }
   ```
3. Another method of the same class:

   ```
   buildMarkup(arrayOfObjects){                      
     let markup = `<div class="container">
                     <div class="${title}" id="${id}">

                      ...iterate here...

                     </div>
                   </div>`
   }
   ```
4. Question: How to iterate in p.3 through `arrayOfObjects` and call `buildItem(obj)` using this template literals? Or maybe there is better way to do this? Something like this didn't work:

   ```
    buildMarkup(arrayOfObjects){                      
     let markup = `<div class="container">
                     <div class="${title}" id="${id}">                           
                       ${arrayOfObjects.forEach(obj => {
                         this.buildItem(obj)    
                         })}
                     </div>
                   </div>`
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People using use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for that:

```
${arrayOfObjects.map(obj => this.buildItem(obj)).join("")}
```

`join` joins the entries of the array created by `map` with the given string in-between them. Since your item strings are `div`s I assume you don't want anything between them, but you could have a space or newline if you prefer. You will want to pass it a string of some kind, though, since its default is `","` which you probably don't want.

If `buildItem` doesn't care what `this` is when it's called and only uses its first parameter (both of which are true for the one in your question), you can leave out the arrow function andpass `buildItem` directly to `map`:

```
${arrayOfObjects.map(this.buildItem).join("")}
```

In context:

```
buildMarkup(arrayOfObjects){                      
  let markup = `<div class="container">
                  <div class="${title}" id="${id}">                           
                    ${arrayOfObjects.map(this.buildItem).join("")}
                  </div>
                </div>`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.forEach()` does not return anything useful (in fact, it returns `undefined`). Try using `.map()`:

```
buildMarkup(arrayOfObjects){                      
  let markup = `<div class="container">
                  <div class="${title}" id="${id}">                           
                    ${arrayOfObjects.map(obj => this.buildItem(obj)).join('\n')}
                  </div>
                </div>`
}
```